# Keep track of MS access updated records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a bound MS Access form which is updated by multiple users.
I want to keep track of any edits by the users. Currently i record whenever a record is updated by using the timestamp and username.environ function
However i would like to track the changed contents as well with an inactive flag.

For example my record is
101 | Software | Jan-2017  | $5600 | Expense for Software (desc) | Active

If someone was to make any change to it, i would like the changed record to be considered active but keep this record as inactive.

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional way to do this sort of thing is with some sort of a flag on the record to indicate the current record (be it a boolean or a sequence number or a date stamp).

Then when you are working with the current data and you end up working on a selection from the table, pruning it down to just what is current (i.e., an sql statement with `where archive_date is null` or `where active = 'T'` or you could do it one the max value for the sequence/date stamp).

That style presents certain problems for bound forms. So your mileage may vary.

My quick and dirty way out of this would be to make a data history table (parallel structure to the one your working with, with an extra date/time field and a userid field), and then add a trigger (ideally at the database level, but you could do it on the controlling form) to log the new value in the history table.

Comment: I have the active or inactive flag. What i need is a history of what has been changed

Comment: In which case, the simplest thing to do is the parallel data history table I mentioned.